# Python convert csv files to a ordered excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv, xlwt

I have in my folder 13 csv files that are named 1,2,3 to 13 (1.csv,2.csv,3csv and so on), and I want to convert them to a single excel file(xlsx) organized in sheets starting to 1 up until 13 but in a numerical order! And for that I used this:

```
import glob, csv, xlwt, os
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
for filename in glob.glob("data/*.csv"):
    (f_path, f_name) = os.path.split(filename)
    (f_short_name, f_extension) = os.path.splitext(f_name)
    ws = wb.add_sheet(f_short_name)
    spamReader = csv.reader(open(filename, 'r'))
    for rowx, row in enumerate(spamReader):
        for colx, value in enumerate(row):
            ws.write(rowx, colx, value)
wb.save("compiled.xlsx")
```

My only problem is that my output: compiled.xlsx won't have the sheets in the order I want (starting from 1,2,3,4,5 ...13), it will start with 4,13,11,12,5,6,8 and so. I have the files in my folder in the desired order, how I can change my code in order to get a proper sheet ordering, I'm using python 3, thanks for your time!

Comment: How about enumerating `glob.glob("data/*.csv")`? `for num, filename in enumerate(glob.glob("data/*.csv")):`. You will have to then use `wb.add_sheet(num+1)`

Comment: sheetname = sheetname.decode(self.encoding) I will get AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: Convert to string `wb.add_sheet(str(num+1))`

Comment: I see, now the sheets are in order but the sheets name won't correspond with their actual data, for example my sheet 1 from excel is the actual 6.csv and so on, same for all sheets, I think the for loops isn't starting with the first csv file like you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort csv files by filename into a list and use that list instead.

I made an assumption that all filenames can be converted to `int` type.

```
files = [os.path.split(filename) for filename in glob.glob("csvs/*.csv")]
ordered_files = sorted(
    files, key=lambda x: int(os.path.splitext(x[1])[0])
)


wb = xlwt.Workbook()
for f_path, f_name in ordered_files:
    (f_short_name, f_extension) = os.path.splitext(f_name)
    ws = wb.add_sheet(f_short_name)
    spamReader = csv.reader(open(os.path.join(f_path, f_name), 'r'))
    for rowx, row in enumerate(spamReader):
        for colx, value in enumerate(row):
            ws.write(rowx, colx, value)
wb.save("compiled.xlsx")
```

Comment: file_names doesn't have any refference

Comment: And also filename from spamReader = csv.reader(open(filename, 'r'))